# Apache not serving pages in /home, but correctly serving pages in /var

Tags: apache

Consider the following Apache configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/yair.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/yair/code/business/public_html

        <Directory /home/yair/code/business/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory />
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The `public_html` directory is configured such:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1      localhost

$ pwd
/home
$ ls -la | grep yair
drwxrwxrw-  49 yair       www-data    4096 Mar 26 10:33 yair

$ cd yair/
$ ls -la | grep code
drwxrwxrw-   4 yair www-data    4096 Mar 26 09:10 code

$ cd code
$ ls -la | grep business
drwxrwxrw-  8 yair www-data 4096 Mar 26 09:11 business

$ cd business/
$ ls -la | grep public
drwxrwxrw- 6 yair www-data 4096 Mar 26 10:33 public_html

$ cd public_html/
$ ls -la | grep index.html 
-rwxrwxrw- 1 yair www-data 4566 Mar 26 09:11 index.html
```

**When I change the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/` and put the files there, Apache serves them as expected. However, with the above configuration Apache complains:**

> You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

What might be the configuration error? This is on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Are you accessing this from the server?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing from Firefox on the same machine as `http://localhost/index.html`. This is a stand-alone desktop machine.

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, will you post the Apache error logs? Also, when you visit `/index.php` does it add an entry to the file: `/var/log/apache2/access_logs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/yair/code/business/public_html

        <Directory /home/yair/code/business/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        <Directory />
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @Yair.R I've updated this to not use named virtual hosts. I don't think this works with localhost.

Comment: Thank you. With this configuration Apache is serving files from `/var/www/`, not from `/home/yair/code/business/public_html/`. I have grepped `/etc/apache2` for the string `/var/www/` but the only place where it appears is in `apache2.conf` on the line `<Directory /var/www/>` which _seems_ to give *directives* for that directory, but does not actually configure Apache to serve from that directory.

Comment: I think the problem is that your are using this from localhost. Apache doesn't like that. I would just use a hostname. Set one up in your `/etc/hosts` file and apache will be fine again. Your original configuration should work fine if you use that (once you update ServerName).

Comment: The string "localhost" is a hostname!

Comment: No it isn't. It is a reserved word. That means it cannot be legally used for things like: `www.localhost`.

Comment: I tried to change the hostname to `yair` in etc/hosts and I still receive the same error

Comment: I know it seems like I'm just making guesses here but I'm literally staring at an almost identical setup to what you have now which works fine. I'm at a loss.

Comment: If all else fails, you could make a link from /home/yair/code/business/public_html to /var/www